# Following query taking too long to execute. How to optimize it

Tags: mysql, sql

I use the following query to get `years` and the `number of movies released in that year` which(referring to a movie) has a female actor.

It executes successfully, but it is taking 4 minutes to execute.
How do I get results in less time?

Also, my disk use goes to more than 70% during this execution.

```
SELECT m.year, COUNT(m.id)
FROM movies m
JOIN roles r ON m.id=r.movie_id
JOIN actors a ON r.actor_id=a.id
WHERE a.gender='F'
GROUP BY m.year;
```

Comment: I am using IMDb movies dataset

Comment: try query in reverse order. means first table should actor join role and join movies table. this might help in performance

Comment: cany you try below query

Comment: SELECT m.year, COUNT(m.id) FROM roles r JOIN actors a ON r.actor_id=a.id 
JOIN movies m ON m.id=r.movie_id WHERE a.gender='F' GROUP BY m.year;

Comment: It also takes the almost same time.

Comment: Does this query return the desired result? If not, then there is no point in improving its performance.

Comment: Yes, it returns the correct result but in 4 minutes 47 seconds.

Comment: Really? So what are you counting? However - You are missing some important indexes on the tables.

Comment: Using subquery we get in 1 minute 30 seconds.

Comment: 1 min 30 is kind of "no significant improvement". How many rows are in the tables? I don't think there are so many movies and actors in the world, that this query would need minutes to execute. What indexes exist (`SHOW CREATE TABLE <table name>`)? How does the execution plan looks like (`EXPLAIN <your query>`)

Comment: This is the dataset we are using here: https://relational.fit.cvut.cz/dataset/IMDb

Comment: Your query takes 17 seconds on my PC. The accepted answer is like 3 times slower (48 sec.). Also the accepted answer doesn't return the same result. So I don't think, you know what you are counting.

Comment: https://imgur.com/Ymuhhgh

Comment: https://imgur.com/GI26mhB

Comment: So your screenshots show different results. If you don't care about the correct result you can also use `select year, floor(rand(1)*1000) as count from movies group by year` - which is much faster.

Comment: Ok, so someone modifies my question and now it's completely different than what I asked for?

Comment: Why do you say it is completely different? I don't see anything different than what was in revision 1. You can roll it back if you feel the edit is wrong.

Comment: Now I have corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use

> EXISTS

instead of JOIN.

```
SELECT m.year, COUNT(m.id) FROM movies m 
where 
exists (select * from roles r where r.movie_id=m.id and 
exists(select * from actors a where a.id=r.actor_id and a.gender='F'))
group by  m.year;
```

To display Total Movies Per Year along with above output.

```
select t1.year,t1.count,t2.total from 
(
SELECT m.year as year, COUNT(m.id) as count FROM movies m 
where exists (select * from roles r where r.movie_id=m.id and exists(select * from actors a where a.id=r.actor_id and a.gender='F'))
group by  m.year
)t1 
join
(select year,count(m.id) as total from movies m group by m.year) t2
on t1.year=t2.year;
```

Comment: Thank you, this reduces the time by 1/4. Please explain how it works.  previous: 4:47 seconds, Now 1.30.

Comment: Thanks..Multiple joins make the query slow and you have to select values only from one table i.e. movies so we can replace joins with Exists which perform better than multiple joins.

Comment: If I also have to select total(or all) movies for every year in the above query. How should be do that?

Comment: total movies per year means without any condition like gender='F', roles and actors?Is it like that?

Comment: yes, but I want to get into the above query itself means along with condition and as well as total

Comment: I have updated the answer, but it may slow down your query as will have to use join for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207097/discussion-between-naveen-arora-and-asis).

Answer (score 1):

Your query is perfectly fine, if it returns the desired result. I've imported the `imdb.sql` and your query executes in 17 seconds on my PC. The EXISTS solution from the other answer needs 48 seconds and returns a different result.

The original tabes are using the MyISAM engine and are quite poorly indexed. After converting the three tables to InnoDB, your query executes in 2.3 seconds. InnoDB takes about twice as much space - But I think it's worth the performance boost.

Then the following changes

```
ALTER TABLE `actors` ADD INDEX `gender` (`gender`);

ALTER TABLE `roles`
    DROP INDEX `idx_actor_id`,
    ADD INDEX `idx_actor_movie` (`actor_id`, `movie_id`);
```

decreased the execution time to 1.7 seconds. That is 10 times faster than with the original schema.

Comment: Please read the question again. and my answer as well. Someone edited the question and makes it completely diffrent.

Comment: In the top section. my asked question and provided answer by me.(In the question section)

Comment: @Asis I don't see your answer. What do you mean?

Comment: query answer which I have provided in the question body itself.