# SQL inner join multiple tables with one query

Tags: mysql

I've a query like below,

```
SELECT
c.testID,
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.ID
INNER JOIN c ON b.r_ID=c.id
WHERE c.test IS NOT NULL;
```

Can this query be optimized further?, I want inner join between three tables to happen only if it meets the where clause.

Comment: just be sure that a.id, b.ID, b.r_ID, c.id, c.test are indexed correctly

Comment: can you tell me what indexed mean? It's all connected correctly with primary and foreign keys.

Comment: look at this question maybe you can find out your answer.https://stackoverflow.com/q/60035994/2286537

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: You might want to use IF ELSE

Comment: @HoussemBadri Can you provide a answer I'm not really familiar with sql queries. I put it together based on google search. It was taking really long

Comment: @Strawberry It's an integer column and there are some null values in it.

Comment: @Strawberry Tables are not indexed in my case.

Comment: @Strawberry I've to index it right? but on what columns do I need to do it? Can we do it without indexing.

Comment: @Strawberry I've went through the create index link if that's what you mean. If possible do provide me some pointers on what to do in more detail. I'm not an expert here.

Comment: Edit your question to provide SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, as well as the EXPLAIN for the given query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try the following:

```
SELECT
c.testID
FROM c 
INNER JOIN b ON c.test IS NOT NULL AND b.r_ID=c.testID 
INNER JOIN a ON a.id=b.r_ID;
```

I changed the order of the joins and conditions so that the first statement to be evaluated is `c.test IS NOT NULL`

**Disclaimer: You should use the explain command in order to see the execution.**
I'm pretty sure that even the minor change I just did might have **no difference due to the [MySql optimizer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer.html)** that work on all queries.

See the [MySQL Documentation: Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html)

### Three queries Compared

Have a look at the following fiddle:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fXsT8oMzJ1H31FwMHrxR3u/0

I ran three different queries and in the end, MySQL optimized and ran them the same way.

[image]

**Three Queries:**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
c.testID
FROM c 
INNER JOIN b ON c.test IS NOT NULL AND b.r_ID=c.testID 
INNER JOIN a ON a.id=b.r_ID;


EXPLAIN SELECT c.testID
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.r_id
INNER JOIN c ON b.r_ID = c.testID AND c.test IS NOT NULL;

EXPLAIN SELECT
c.testID
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.r_ID
INNER JOIN c ON b.r_ID=c.testID
WHERE c.test IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Where clause works as filter on the data what appears after all JOINs,
whereas if you use same restriction to JOIN clause itself then it will be optimized in sense of avoiding filter after join. That is, join on filtered data instead.

```
SELECT c.testID,
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.ID
INNER JOIN c ON b.r_ID = c.id AND c.test IS NOT NULL;
```

Moreover, you must create an index for the column `test` in table `c` to speed up the query.

Also, learn EXPLAIN command to the queries for best results.

Answer (score 0):

All tables should have a `PRIMARY KEY`.  Assuming that `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` for the tables that it is in, then you need these secondary keys for maximal performance:

```
c:  INDEX(test, test_id, id)  -- `test` must be first
b:  INDEX(r_ID)
```

Both of those are useful and "covering".

Another thing to note:  `b` and `a` is virtually unused in the query, so you may as well write the query this way:

```
SELECT c.testID,
    FROM c
    WHERE c.test IS NOT NULL;
```

At that point, all you need is `INDEX(test, testID)`.

I suspect you "simplified" your query by leaving out some uses of `a` and `b`.  Well, I simplified it from there, just as the Optimizer should have done.  (However, elimination of tables is an optimization that it does not do; it figures that is something the user *would have done*.)

On the other hand, `b` and `a` are not totally useless.  The `JOIN` verify that there are corresponding rows, possibly many such rows, in those tables.  Again, I think you had some other purpose.